# On async return type

Tags: c#, asynchronous, language-design, return-type

Wondering why we should specify that `async` method does return Task object.

Specifying it seems redundant with the `async` keyword plus it is confusion since you do not really create the `Task` object.

As I understand the compiler does emit the necessary code for Task object creation (Whether on a await call or wrapping the return with a new Task.).

I don't really like the inconsistency between the declare type and the return Type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have [a blog post](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2011/09/async-ctp-why-do-keywords-work-that-way.html) that describes the reasoning in detail. Inferring the return type [was considered](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/async/thread/0ee0af6a-3034-4ac3-aa82-cb6bd62a9ab9#8d1826a5-d603-4b74-8c64-2a9b32d6af24) but they decided not to.

With the explicit return type, the `async` keyword is more of an implementation detail. There are two reasons to have the explicit return type:

- The method signature is consistent (it's the same at the point of declaration as when observed using IntelliSense or reflection).
- There is a difference between `async void` and `async Task`. With an inferred return type, there's no clear way to define an `async void` method.

Comment: I understand the difference of `async void` and `async Task` void. So I rather prefer to have an explicit return of a new Task `return Task<Whatever>(something)`,(which would make `async` keyword useless I guess).

Comment: @mathk: That would be even worse; it would imply that it's creating a `Task` instance at that point, which is completely false.  And, the `async` modifier would still be needed.

Answer (score 8):

This isn't really a question: it's more of a rant and therefore not particularly suitable for StackOverflow:

> I don't really like the inconsistency between the declare type and the return type.

If you want to complain, start a blog and complain on that. Let's reformulate that as a *question*:

> The declared type returned by an `async` method might be, say `Task<int>` but the expression returned by a `return` statement in that method must be implicitly convertible to `int`, not `Task<int>`. This is potentially confusing. What design principle justifies this behaviour?

You are right that this is potentially confusing. It is confusing because `async` methods separate two things that we are very used to thinking of as one thing. Those two things are:

- What type of object is returned when control resumes in the *caller* of this method?
- What type of object is passed from the method to its *continuation*? Remember that the *continuation* of a method is *the code that runs when the method completes*.

In synchronous methods those two things are always the same because **the point of resumption in the caller *is* the continuation of a synchronous method**.  But the whole point of an asynchronous method is that the code in the caller is *not* the continuation of the method. The continuation of the method is controlled by setting the continuation of the task associated with it.

That's why the declared return type and the type given to the `return` statement are different. The caller wants a `Task<int>` but the *continuation* of the method wants an `int`.  The `return` statement means "this method is done; give this value to my continuation" regardless of whether the method is synchronous or asynchronous.

Comment: Depending on how the Task is consumed, the continuation may also get a `Task<T>`.

Comment: You've also raised a better point, which is that the OP should be asking for `async throw` as well.  (which would actually make more sense, since it becomes a failed `Task<T>` rather than an exception)

Comment: @SLaks: Indeed. Another way to look at it is that there are *two* continuations associated with any method: the "regular" continuation and the "exceptional" continuation. In synchronous methods the exceptional continuation is the nearest enclosing `finally` or matching `catch`. In async methods the error continuation is determined by the code which uses the task.

Comment: But one could have design an `async return` in the  async method so that it is clear that you are not doing a regular return. Like the yield for iterator. Sounds less confusing.

Comment: " implicitly convertible to int" -- Thanks to primitive type?

Comment: @mathk: I also cover the `async return` option in [my blog post](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2011/09/async-ctp-why-do-keywords-work-that-way.html). To summarize: `async return` doesn't add much real clarification; it just makes it harder to convert code from synchronous to `async`.

Comment: @mathk: We considered it and as Stephen says, rejected it. (And as SLaks points out, you'd need to also make "async throw".)  If given the opportunity to redesign C# 2.0, I'd probably make the same choice for iterator blocks: `iterator IEnumerable<int> X() { return 1; }` rather than `IEnumerable<int> X() { yield return 1; }`.

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you're asking why `public async int MyMethodAsync()` isn't automatically compiled as a method that actually returns `Task<int>`.

The answer is the principle of least surprise: The declared return type in the method signature is always the actual return type.
This way, when you read a method declaration, you can always know the actual return type as seen when calling the method, without needing to look at modifiers and remember special rules.

Comment: Yes and no, I would prefer to have consistency between the return type and the declare type.

Comment: @mathk: If you're writing the method, you need to understand the modifier anyway, so that's less important.  Also, look at iterators, which came first.  (and which your argument does not apply to)

Comment: I am glad you  point out the iterator, because to me it is a better way of designing such method. It is a new kind of return  `yield return`. I rather have the async keyword at the return statement. It explicit the fact that you are not really returning the object directly. It yield an other question, why did async syntax have been implement differently than yield?

Comment: @mathk: All of the "magic" about async happens not at `return` but at `await`.  There return statement is not particularly special, and may not exist at all.  Besides, what keyword would you use?

Comment: `aync return` like  the `yield return`

Comment: That is an interesting idea; I don't know why they didn't do it.  Probably because, unlike iterators, the `return` isn't the point of this feature.

Comment: I think it would be less confusing why one should not return a Task. You would have notice that I did the confusion in the other comment :).

Comment: `async return` doesn't really make sense. That's not where the async is taking place. You could have several asynchronous calls within the method and only one return. With this approach you would actually explicitly say async where there's no async and the other way around.

Comment: @Kenneth: It makes some sense, in that it isn't (usually) returning synchronously to the caller.